# App crashing on launch with instrumentation w/ calabash-ios

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, calabash, calabash-ios

UPDATE: This was fixed by resetting the phone's settings. General -> Reset -> "Reset all settings".

We are having on issue on iPhones 6 and 6+ when launching our IBM MobileFirst-based app.

When calabash instrumentation is linked and I manually launch the app, the splash screen will come up and the app will quit almost instantly.

Double tapping home shows me the app running in the background, but Xcode does not recognize it as a running process. After force-closing the app and re-launching, it will usually do the same thing, but sometimes it comes up.

I've noticed our automation is sometimes stuck in an infinite loop of launching and crashing. This only happens on the instrumented app.

The crash log throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I [found a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/calabash-ios/Abv_-aH9VLM/VZS_BPlQNicJ) on the google group from a few years back that talks about linker flags, but I don't have any of the weaker flags mentioned there.

Steps to reproduce:

*App must be instrumented with the calabash automation framework (`calabash-ios setup` must have been executed in same directory as xcodeproj file.)

1. Build application and deploy native iOS project to XCode via eclipse.
2. Build the -cal target with the "Run" configuration.
3. Kill the debugger/application.
4. Manually launch the app on the device.  The app will successfully launch maybe 15%-20% of the time, otherwise it will just quit.

Using calabash-cucumber version 0.14.3.

Linker flags:
$(inherited)
-force_load
"$(SRCROOT)/calabash.framework/calabash"
-lstdc++

It appears $(inherited) contains -ObjC for Debug.

Xcode installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Xcode version: 6.1.1
Xcode build: 6A2008a

Comment: Step-by-step reproduction steps would be of more help.

Comment: Without "calabash" does your application crash? Also, is this a hybrid application, native ios, or xamarin?

Comment: No, app does not crash without calabash.  It is a hybrid IBM MobileFirst app.

Comment: What versions of Calabash and Xcode are you using?  What are your linker flags for the Calabash target?  What do the logs say? https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki#reporting-problems https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Hot-Topics#viewing-device-logs

Comment: Updated with additional information

Comment: @jmoody, any thoughts based on tuggles' update?

Comment: Actually I just found the fix to this.  What I had to do is reset the phone's settings in Settings -> General -> Reset -> "Reset All Settings" (the first option).  Have not seen the behavior since.

Comment: @tuggles, please either remove the question or write the above as an answer for others to benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

The user is unresponsive, the fix was:

> Actually I just found the fix to this. What I had to do is reset the
>   phone's settings in Settings -> General -> Reset -> "Reset All
>   Settings" (the first option). Have not seen the behavior since.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem, tried so many different ways and finally found how to fix it - I changed project directory, pulled from Git, then bundle install, pod install and build the app with calabash target as usual

Xcode 7.3.1, calabash-cucumber (0.19.1)